# How to fix the error "Objects are not valid as a react child. (found: [object Promise])" in the appDir in next js 13 app

Tags: next.js, sanity

```
"use client";

import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import Image from "next/image";
import { client } from "../../../../lib/sanity.client";
import urlFor from "../../../../lib/urlFor";
import { PortableText } from "@portabletext/react";
import { RichTextComponents } from "../../../../components/RichTextComponents";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";

interface IFormInput {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  comment: string;
}

type Props = {
  params: {
    slug: string;
  };
};

export const revalidate = 30;

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const query = groq`
    *[_type=="post"]
    {
      slug
    }
  `;
  const slugs: Post[] = await client.fetch(query);
  const slugRoutes = slugs.map((slug) => slug.slug.current);

  return slugRoutes.map((slug) => ({
    slug,
  }));
}

const Post = async ({ params: { slug } }: Props) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<IFormInput>();
  const query = groq`
    *[_type=='post' && slug.current == $slug][0]
    {
        ...,
        author->,
        categories[]->
    }
  `;
  const post: Post = await client.fetch(query, { slug });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = async (data) => {
    await fetch("/api/createComment", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <article className="px-10 pb-28 mt-10">
        <section className="space-y-2 borber border-[#f7ab0a] text-white">
          <div className="relative min-h-56 flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between">
            <div className="absolute top-0 w-full h-full opacity-10 blur-sm p-10">
              <Image
                className="object-cover object-center mx-auto"
                src={urlFor(post.mainImage).url()}
                alt={post.author.name}
                fill
              />
            </div>
            <section className="p-5 bg-[#f7ab0a] w-full">
              <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between gap-y-5">
                <div>
                  <h1 className="text-4xl font-extrabold">{post.title}</h1>
                  <p>
                    {new Date(post._createdAt).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
                      day: "numeric",
                      month: "long",
                      year: "numeric",
                    })}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                  <Image
                    className="rounded-full"
                    src={urlFor(post.author.image).url()}
                    alt={post.author.name}
                    height={40}
                    width={40}
                  />
                  <div className="w-64">
                    <h3 className="text-lg font-bold">{post.author.name}</h3>
                    <div> {/* */} </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <h2 className="italic pt-10">{post.description}</h2>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-end mt-auto space-x-2">
                  {post.categories.map((category) => (
                    <p
                      className="bg-gray-800 text-white px-3 py-1 rounded-full text-sm font-semibold mt-4"
                      key={category._id}
                    >
                      {category.title}
                    </p>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </section>
        <PortableText value={post.body} components={RichTextComponents} />
      </article>
      <div>
        <hr className="max-w-lg my-5 mx-auto border border-yellow-500" />
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className="flex flex-col p-5 max-w-2xl mx-auto mb-10"
        >
          <h3 className="text-md text-yellow-500">Enjoyed this article?</h3>
          <h4 className="text-3xl font-bold">Leave a comment below!</h4>
          <hr className="py-3 mt-2" />

          <input
            {...register("_id")}
            type="hidden"
            name="_id"
            value={post._id}
          />
          <label className="block mb-5 ">
            <span className="text-gray-700">Name</span>
            <input
              {...register("name", { required: true })}
              className="shadow border rounded py-2 px-3 form-input mt-1 block w-full outline-none ring-yellow-500 focus:ring"
              placeholder="John Doe..."
              type="text"
            />
          </label>
          <label className="block mb-5 ">
            <span className="text-gray-700">Email</span>
            <input
              {...register("email", { required: true })}
              className="shadow border rounded py-2 px-3 form-input mt-1 block w-full outline-none ring-yellow-500 focus:ring"
              placeholder="example@gmail.com"
              type="email"
            />
          </label>
          <label className="block mb-5 ">
            <span className="text-gray-700">Comment</span>
            <textarea
              {...register("comment", { required: true })}
              className="shadow border rounded py-2 px-3 form-textarea mt-1 block w-full outline-none ring-yellow-500 focus:ring"
              placeholder="type your comments..."
              rows={8}
            />
          </label>

          <div className="flex flex-col p-5">
            {errors.name && (
              <span className="text-red-500">
                -- The name field is required
              </span>
            )}
            {errors.email && (
              <span className="text-red-500">
                -- The email field is required
              </span>
            )}
            {errors.comment && (
              <span className="text-red-500">
                -- The comment field is required
              </span>
            )}
          </div>

          <input
            type="submit"
            className="shadow bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-400 w-full
      focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded cursor-pointer
     "
          />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="relative">
        <a
          id="topp"
          rel="noreferrer"
          href="#top"
          className="back-to-top absolute bottom-4 right-0 rounded-3xl bg-[#f7ab0a] text-white hover:-translate-y-2 hover:bg-lime-600 hover:text-[#f7ab0a] p-2 text-2xl"
        >
          <i className="fas fa-angle-up " aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

I tried to post comments from my blog post to sanity v3 studio backend. But whenever I tried to test on the localhost:3000 dev build it claims that "**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."** I didn't understand where I render children as object.

I would like have my comment function working, this problem to be solved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following line in your `Post` component is causing the issue:

```
// ...
 const post: Post = await client.fetch(query, { slug });
// ...
```

You are using `post` variable to access `title`, `author`, `categories` fields and trying to render it in the JSX.

However, `post` is a `Promise` which is not resolved while React is rendering the component.

So, basically you are rendering `Promise` inside the JSX which is not supported (that's what the error is saying)

So, the better way is to define a `state` for `post` variable and make an api call inside a function and when that api is resolved set the response data inside the `post` state and use that post state inside the JSX.

Something like:

```
const Post = async ({ params: { slug } }: Props) => {

    //... your component body

    const [post, setPost] = useState(null) // initialise post state to be null


    const fetchPost = async() => {
        try {
            let response = await client.fetch(query, { slug })
            setPost(response.data) // it will be response.data or something else based on your response structure where you are getting the post
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPost()
    }, [])

    // .... remaining code

    // handle loader
    if(!post) return <p>loading...</p>

    return (
        <>
            {/* JSX similar to what you are rendering */}
        </>
    )
}
```

You can create separate `loader` state in the component to handle loading more accurately.

Let me know if you have further queries. Happy to resolve them! :-)